# How to trigger EMail messages in using the engagement plan

Tags: sitecore, ecm

I am using ECM 2.1 for sending out emails.
I want to know how can I added the triggered emails to all the recipients who have opened the email and who are productive users on the email sent.
Can I modify the existing plan and add this feature.

Answer (score 0):

By Using **tokenized emails**

An action that can be executed from within a Sitecore Engagement Plan is to send an email to a static or to the visitors email address.

follow this link:
http://www.newguid.net/sitecore/2013/sending-tokenized-emails-from-a-sitecore-engagement-plan/